# error #1009 can't access property of null object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm newbie here i got an eror where i can't load external swf from my main fla the ouput said like this

```
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject/construct()
    at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject()
    at com.asgamer.basics1::Ship()
    at com.asgamer.basics1::Engine()`
```

I create a button and tried to load swf file called basics1 which content all those classes above, and i using action code snippet to load swf file
    please help i'm not a programmer sorry if my question in easy

Comment: Without any code it is rather difficult to tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: The error is very clear your question no. Please post the code

Answer (score 0):

the problem is fix by adding this

```
 if(stage) {
        initialize();
    } else {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    }
} 

private function initialize(e:Event = null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    //  here goes the code that's currently in Engine constructor
}
```

after public function engine